# Category links break the https

Tags: https

I have asked my hosting company to active the https for my web site. Now, when I write the URL in my browser and go to my web site it is https (I can see the green lock). I have some Menu items which direct to some pages I have created, all works fine. However, links which direct to example.com/category/holidays etc. breaks the https. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: Try to go to Wordpress Settings > Permalinks and save. This will refresh the urls. (Also change the home(WordPress Address (URL)) and site url(Site Address (URL))  so it includes the https://yourawesomewebsite.com). As a final step clear cache and cookies.

Comment: thx for the comment, I did what you said but did not solve the problem

Comment: Define what you mean by "breaks the https" you see something to the console of the web browser?

Comment: yes, actually you are right I need to define. I see the gray lock with ! on Firefox

Comment: This probably means there are resources like images, text, css, that take something from `HTTP` sites or not secure. So I would open the developing tools (F12) and see the message in the console.

Comment: you are very right, after opening the console I have seen that there was one image that I assigned as a banner photo which was uploading from the http link. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new or not so new move to the https side of thing, there are rising numbers of questions about the mixed content warning for https.

### First check the sites URLS:

- Settings > Permalinks and save. This will refresh the urls.
- Also change WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) so it
  includes the **https**://yourawesomewebsite.com).
- As a final step clear cache and cookies

### Steps to verifying:

- Open the developer tools( Chrome/Firefox F12)
- Navigate to console and
  see the complete error/warning